# Python Dynamic Query on Strings

Tags: python, mysql

I want to run a Dynamic query in python.

I have a combobox with 4 values (Direct, Indirect, Intermediary, Pointed).  What I want to do is to write a dynamic query to interrogate my database and return the count of items.
I have this code:
(`val` is used to retrieve the value from a combobox)

```
c=db.cursor()
val=var.get()
query='SELECT count(*) from table where field=' + val
c.execute(query)
```

Now the query works if I write it like `query='SELECT count(*) from table where field="Direct"'` but I want it to work dynamically.

Is there any solution?

Comment: what orm are you using? you should bind parameters to your query instead of concatenating a string.. it opens you to sql injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this maybe?

```
db.execute("SELECT count(*) from table where field = %s", [val])
```

this is assuming you are using pymssql which uses "%s" to bind parameters

Comment: You just saved my day. Thanks a lot! Owe you one.

Comment: @NickDragosh glad I could help! this is also a much more secure way of executing a query because if some random user hits your function they could literally destroy your database `query='SELECT count(*) from table where field="' + val + '"'` if they made val be `val='"; DROP DATABASE;'` you would be in trouble :) dont forget to mark the answer as accepted when you have a chance!

Comment: Yup. Did it. Thanks for the suggestion as well. Cheers!